# how to change package version number for angular cli library using ng command

Tags: angular-cli-v6

I have created an angular library using `angular cli` library command `ng g library libname` and published it into npm repository. Now whenever I change something in the library, I have to go to the library folder and run `npm version <version-type>` to update version number before publishing to npm. I did not see a `ng` command to update the version number of the library.

is there any `ng` command to update the library version from root folder?

[Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10825) issue to track the feature

Comment: it will reduce many steps by not going inside the library folder any time

Answer (score 1):

You should add `npm version patch` as a "prebuild" script, this way before each build will increment your patch number in the version attribute

Comment: It will update the original project not the library. Library package.json is inside the library folder

Comment: That is what my questions is. I was asking to have a ng command directly outside which will change the library version from outside. I know the command you are saying. BTW thanks for answering

Comment: and what if you create a new command like this `"build-library": cd <lib_folder> && npm version patch`